# Change icon size in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, icons

How does one change the default icon size for toolbar icons and such?

Comment: By GNOME3 you mean `gnome-shell`? Right?

Comment: No, I mean Gnome 3. I want to change the icons in the Banshee toolbar (which have a system-set size).

Answer (score 3):

See this blog post:

- [Gnome3 Customization | Change Icon Size](http://abhizweblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/gnome3-change-icon-size.html)

Unfortunately, these system-wide changes are likely to be gone after the next update... To per-user changes, refer to this blog post:

- [Per-user Gnome 3 configuration](https://web.archive.org/web/20140607011322/http://therning.org/magnus/archives/933)

(It is about Arch Linux, but I think it is applicable)

Install `user-theme` extension for `gnome-shell`, then copy themes to your home folders as written, modify them as you like, and choose your new user-modified theme in the `gnome-tweak-tool`.